# Skip transparent background in an image when setting an image as background in android

Tags: android, image

I am working on a project in which I am using a lot of images. My friend has designed all the images in photoshop and all those images are of my required size. 
But the problem is that when my friend exported those images from the photoshop, he exported those images with a transparent background and that transparent background with the image makes the frame size bigger than required. And when I set that image to some ImageView, it expands to the whole screen due to its bigger frame size.

Now my question is that Is there a way to set image in imageview so that the transparent part is automatically ignored and the image of my required size just sets into the imageview. Or It is required to crop those images in photoshop and then use those images.

I am sorry if someone couldn't understand the question but I can elaborate if asked.

Comment: try scaleType="centerCrop" in xml for that imageView CenterInside fitCenter are some other values. play with it to see if it can solve your issue.

Comment: @Sahil setting scale type to "centerCrop" does crops the center but the frame is still big enough that it occupies a large screen area due to the transparent part in the image.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be just edit them in photoshop, but I found another way if you want to look into it. Its called webP and you can check it out [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/webp). With this you can skip the transparency, but I think the size would stay the same, You can try it out if you want though.

Hope this helps!